# WSO2 identity server java 8 support

Tags: wso2, wso2-identity-server

WSO Identity Server 5.0.0 does not start with java 8. Probably because the underlying equinox version doesn't support it. 
My question is: Will WSO2 Identity Server 5.1.0 support java 8?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

WSO2IS 5.0.0 only supports for Java 6 and 7. Any WSO2 product does not support for java8 now.  But they are currently working on it. See [here](https://github.com/wso2/carbon4-kernel/tree/java8support). It seems be java8 support would be available soon for Carbon kernel. Therefore most probably WSO2IS 5.1.0 would support Java8

Comment: Thanks. That is good news. I always expected IS 5.1.0 to be released around April/15 and if the carbon kernel is not yet supporting Java 8, I wonder if that timeline can be kept.

Comment: It seems to be 5.1.0 is planned for May..  https://wso2.org/jira/browse/IDENTITY Sometime may be late.. So it may have the support of Java8 :)